# Install App on SDK 22 leads into error at Bitmapfactory

Tags: android, bitmap, sdk, version

I wrote an app and so far i always build it on sdk level 25. Now I wanted to try to run it on a lower level but it crashes. While debugging I figured out that this link gives the error:

```
bitmapBackgroundColors = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.background_colors);
```

Do you have any idea how it can destroy like everything? :D
Bitmapfactory is alive since SDK 1, so this cant really be the problem.

My compileSdkVersion is 25, my minSdkVersion 15 and my targetSdkVersion 25. (Although I still dont rly understand what these numbers mean)

Edit: The error is an OutOfMemory Error. But the .jpg it has to load is just 128kb big

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 223948812 byte allocation with 8134272 free bytes and 180MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:467)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:497)
    at com.cucumbertroup.strawberry.strawberry.GameView.<init>(GameView.java:136)
    at com.cucumbertroup.strawberry.strawberry.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Edit2: So probably I am making some mistakes with the decoding of the image.
How could i do it more efficiently than that:

```
bitmapBackgroundColors = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.background_colors);
bitmapBackgroundColors = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapBackgroundColors, screenX * 3, screenY, false);
```

Comment: What is the error message displayed in LogCat (caused by ???).

Comment: take a look at the edit

Answer (score 1):

Using [BitmapFactory.decodeResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource(android.content.res.Resources,%20int)) doesn´t no have nothing to do with the sdk level:

```
bitmapBackgroundColors = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.background_colors);
```

the problem here

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 223948812 byte
>   allocation with 8134272 free bytes and 180MB until OOM

is that the capacity of memory storage on every device is different. So you have to optimize your images.

Check this articles with tips to optimize your images:

[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)

[Handling Bitmaps decodeResource](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidApplicationOptimization/article.html#handling-bitmaps)

As an example you will use this method

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

And call it to get a smaller version of the original image:

```
//bitmapBackgroundColors = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.background_colors);
bitmapBackgroundColors = 
decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.background_colors, 500, 500);
```

This is another article to optimize your images to be used in your project:

[Reducing Image Download Sizes](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/network-xfer.html)

Comment: i mean it should be the width and the height of the picture i wanna draw, but is not, because even when i put two time the same number the picture does not get transformed

Comment: no i mean as an example you will get a smaller version of the original imagen as bitmap, in this example of 500 x 500px that mean least quantity of bytes. What is the size of image background_colors in bytes?

Comment: its a 3240x1920 picture with 125.883 Bytes

Comment: 3240x1920 only 125,883 Bytes or KB ?

Comment: Definitly Bytes. Thats the reason why I was so confused. When I draw the picture it needs 10 times more space then it actually "weights".